# will the response of YouTube comments API preserve the order of the ids filter?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm using https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list.
and I will provide ids of threads I want as a filter: (e.g. part=snippet&id=id1,id2)

> The id parameter specifies a comma-separated list of comment thread IDs for the resources that should be retrieved.

will the results order match the id order? will I get thread with id1 first and id2 second? from experimentation it seems like it. but can I rely on that?